# How to automatically run Selenium WebDriver test cases

Tags: visual-studio-2010, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created dozens of my test cases using Selenium WebDriver using .Net (c#) and my question is:

Is there a way to run all my test cases run on schedule?

Currently I'm running my test cases manually in Visual Studio!

Any help?

Comment: Most often people combine it with a CI solution (like TeamCity). However, you can just as easily call the MSTest or NUnit command line instead.

Comment: how do i call MSTest through command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CruiseControl is open source, and can do what TeamCity can do (just without the awesome interface, it may take some figuring out)

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

MSTest command line options documentation live here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.80).aspx

You can wrap it into a batch file and launch it using Windows Scheduled Tasks.

If you want to load *all* tests, it is pretty simply, just:

`mstest.exe /testcontainer:Assembly.dll`

Replacing `Assembly.dll` with the compiled test project assembly. The MSDN documentation should suffice. If not, feel free come back and ask

Comment: Walkthrough: Using the Command-line Test Utility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule to run your tests from a Continous Integration service like TeamCity.

Comment: is there anything i can do within the Visual Studio? my management will not allow to go with teamcity or any other third party except if that product is open source

Comment: CruiseControl and Hudson are open-source solutions, that do a similar job to TeamCity. I am not aware of anything that will schedule test-runs in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

***Jenkins/Hudson*** is another great third party Open source Continous Integration tool with a neat interface.
Pretty good community and plenty of plugins/add ons.

Extremely easy to setup and get going as well.
More info [here](http://jenkins-ci.org/).